# PHP - add new WHERE clause to SQL statement within foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, ajax, foreach, where-clause

I've got a checkbox filter where multiple options can be 'checked'. Once they are checked they are stored in a JavaScript array and passed to the php file via ajax. From there, I'm trying to do a foreach loop to get each element in the array and add a new where condition to the SQL statement for each element, and run the query.

**JavaScript**

```
var vendors = [];

function filterResults($this)
{
  var vendor = $($this).attr('data-id');
  if($($this).prop('checked'))
  {
    var action = 'add';
    vendors.push(vendor);
  }
  else
  {
    var action = 'remove';
    var index = vendors.indexOf(vendor);
    if(index >= 0)
    {
        vendors.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

**PHP Script that is run (filter-results.php)**

```
if(is_array($_POST['vendors']))
{
   $collaterals = $vendor->updateResults($_POST['vendors']);
   var_dump($collaterals);

   foreach($collaterals as $col)
   {
     include '../parts/item.php';
   }
}
```

**PHP Function containing foreach loop**

```
public function updateResults($vendors)
{
    try
    {   
        $items = array();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM collaterals WHERE ";
        foreach ($vendors as $ven)
        {
            echo $ven;
            $sql .= "vendor = ".$ven." OR ";
        }

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        while($row = $stmt->fetchObject())
        {
            $items[] = $row;
        }

        return $items;

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The 'echo' within the PHP function is working, but the var_dump() is turning 'NULL' which means there is an error within the SQL statement somewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can this run query without `foreach` loop as follows

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM collaterals WHERE vendor IN ('".implode("','",$vendors)."')";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. All answers where extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks like

```
SELECT * FROM collaterals WHERE vendor = x OR vendor = x OR
```

You must remove the last OR.
Also i would suggest using the IN clause with implode() php function.

Answer (score 0):

it will produce "SELECT * FROM collaterals WHERE vendor = 1 OR vendor = 2 OR "

use "Select * FROM collaterals where vendor in(1,2,3)" instead,

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

1. You're using `vendor = item1 OR vendor = item2 OR` (notice the hanging OR)
2. Using `IN` achieves the same result
3. You should be using prepared statements

Do this:

```
$items = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM collaterals WHERE vendor IN (".
     implode(",",array_fill(0, count($vendors), "?")) 
.")";
// $sql would look like e.g. SELECT * FROM collaterals WHERE vendor IN (?,?,?)
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($vendors);
```

Note: All `$vendors` will be treated as strings in the above code, if you need to bind them as a different type you should call `bindParam` or `bindValue` on each array entry